# How to remove trailing decimals without rounding up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example, I have a number `123.429`. How can I remove the trailing decimals without rounding up to two decimal place.
Hence, I need the number to be up to two d.p. i.e `123.42`.

Definitely `toFixed()` method or `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` cannot be used in this situation.

Comment: what's wrong with your solutions? Just to understand what we can not suggest

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use `toFixed` or `Math.round()`? How did you get to this number in the first place?

Comment: Is there anyway to mask away the trailing decimals? I do not want to round up that why I specify it in this question. e.g 123.429, I want it to be 123.42!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var number = parseInt('' + (num * 100)) / 100;
```

Comment: As OP said *Definitely toFixed() method or Math.round(num * 100) / 100 cannot be used in this situation*

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan the OP is wrong - `.toFixed` can certainly be used.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan That's what the OP *thinks*. It's not (hopefully) some arbitrary rule they have to follow.

Comment: for what I know it could be a code challenge. or maybe he is just a student who wants to know a different approach - just saying

Comment: Math.round() would round up - this is what the OP does not want. My approach will not round - just "clip" it.

Comment: @Alnitak, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170463/how-to-remove-trailing-decimals-without-rounding-up/28170573#comment44711358_28170871 OP cit. : *I was look for a different approach in solving this problem*

Answer (score 14):

The function you want is `Math.floor(x)` to remove decimals without rounding up (so `floor(4.9) = 4`).

`var number = Math.floor(num * 100) / 100;`

---

**Edit:** I want to update my answer because actually, this rounds *down* with negative numbers:

```
var Math.floor(-1.456 * 100) / 100;
```

> -1.46

However, since Javascript 6, they have introduced the [`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) function which truncates to an int without rounding, as expected. You can use it the same way as my proposed usage of `Math.floor()`:

```
var number = Math.trunc(num * 100) / 100;
```

Alternatively, the `parseInt()` method proposed by awe works as well, although requires a string allocation.

Comment: Math.floor exactly round down the number which definitely does not help in my case.   "The floor() method rounds a number DOWNWARDS to the nearest integer, and returns the result."

Comment: Yes...but since you are multiplying by 100 and then dividing after the `floor()` function, you are keeping the decimals. You specified without rounding - this will turn your 123.429 to 123.42 as you asked.

Comment: Ic.My mistake. I was look for a different approach in solving this problem.

Comment: OK, no problem. I'll leave my answer here in case anyone searches for the same problem.

Comment: Just to clarify: This _will_ give same result as my answer that was accepted - and in my humble opinion better than my answer, because it does not go through string and number parsing. It is pure math.

Comment: I updated the answer, because it rounds away from zero for negative numbers. However, since Javascript 6, `Math.trunc()` is available for use, so I recommend that instead of `Math.floor()`.

Answer (score 2):

another v. cool solution is by using | operator

```
let num = 123.429 | 0
```

```js
let num = 123.429 | 0

console.log(num);
```

Comment: This does not work for big numbers, try `45646546544444444444456004646.1 | 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a string and then simply truncate the string two places after the decimal, e.g.:

```
var s = String(123.429);
s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.') + 3);  //   "123.42"
```

Please note that there's no guarantee if you convert that final string back into a number that it'll be *exactly* representable to those two decimal places - computer floating point math doesn't work that way.

Comment: Not the downvoter but what's the point of first applying `.toFixed()` before truncating? You could just cast to string.

Comment: @Juhana casting to a string might produce exponential format

Comment: `.toFixed()` won't help you there.

Comment: @Juhana hmm, so it doesn't.   will amend.

Answer (score 0):

let's get the variable name as "num"

```
var num = 123.429;
num=num*100;
num=num.toString();
num=num.split(".");
num=parseInt(num[0]);
num=num/100;
```

value of the num variable will be 12.42

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
number = parseFloat(number).toFixed(12);
number = number.substring(0, number.indexOf('.') + 3);

return parseFloat(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest solution but the only one that handles an edge case like `0.0006*10000 = 5.999999999` properly, i.e. if you want to truncate to 4 decimal places and the value is exactly 0.0006, then using `Math.trunc(0.0006 * (10 ** 4))/(10 ** 4)` gives you `0.0005`.